# Is there a better way to write this Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-optimization

I'm working on removing weekends from my data. Weekends in the countries `AE` and `SA` are Friday and Saturday and every other country are Saturday and Sunday.

This is a preview of my data,

[image]

And this is my attempt of the query,

```
SELECT*
FROM
(SELECT
  Country,
  date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', date) AS dow
FROM `xxx.xxx.date`
ORDER BY date)
WHERE 
(country IN ('AE', 'SA') AND NOT (dow LIKE 'Friday' OR dow LIKE 'Saturday')) OR
country NOT IN ('AE', 'SA') AND NOT (dow LIKE 'Saturday' OR dow LIKE 'Sunday')
ORDER BY date
```

Is there a way to store variable for example rather than listing each country twice in the query?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `LIKE` with `dow`, as you seem to want string equality here.  Other than this, your current query seems fine and I wouldn't change anything.

Comment: ok perfect! thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I've replaced `LIKE` with  `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer, because there are a handful of minor stylistic changes you can make to the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Country, date, FORMAT_DATE('%A', date) AS dow
    FROM `xxx.xxx.date`
) t
WHERE 
    country IN ('AE', 'SA') AND dow NOT IN ('Friday', 'Saturday') OR
    country NOT IN ('AE', 'SA') AND dow NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
ORDER BY
    date;
```

In the above, I have replaced `LIKE` with `IN`, since you seem to want to use equality with `dow`.  In addition, `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, letting us do away with some unneeded parentheses.

**Edit:**

We can even write your query in a succinct way without any subquery:

```sql
SELECT Country, date, FORMAT_DATE('%A', date) AS dow
FROM `xxx.xxx.date`
WHERE 
    country IN ('AE', 'SA') AND FORMAT_DATE('%u', date) NOT IN (5, 6) OR
    country NOT IN ('AE', 'SA') AND FORMAT_DATE('%u', date) NOT IN (6, 7)
ORDER BY
    date;
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the `t` that you've added just before `WHERE`?

Comment: Most databases require that derived tables, subqueries, etc., require an explicit alias.  If BigQuery doesn't require this, then watch out, because just about every other database requires it.

Comment: The subquery seems unnecessary, no?

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann The original intention of the subquery was likely to avoid repetition of the `FORMAT_DATE` call in the `WHERE` clause.  But, if we use the `%u` mask, we can still get pretty concise syntax, avoiding the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT Country, date, FORMAT_DATE('%A', date) AS dow
      FROM `xxx.xxx.date`
     ) t
WHERE (CASE WHEN country IN ('AE', 'SA') 
            THEN dow NOT IN ('Friday', 'Saturday')
            ELSE dow NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
       END)
ORDER BY date;
```

I'm not usually a fan of `CASE` expressions in `WHERE` clauses, but this does specifically answer your question.